# Test of sample mean when mean and variance are not independent

Tags: t-test, survival, heteroscedasticity

I have a dataset in which I have predicted risk probabilities from a survival model.  The probability predictions were made at two different times for each observation - similar to a repeated measures outcome.  I want to do a test of the mean to see if the predicted values change between timepoints.

Typically, I would used a paired t-test, but in this case the  mean and the variance of the measurement are not independent due to being predicted risk probabilities from a survival analysis.  The variance at the extreme ends of probability predictions is smaller than risk probabilities in the center - essentially a non-constant variance dependent upon where on the probability scale the measurement is located, which violates the t-test assumption that the mean and variance are independent.

What would be a good alternative to the paired t-test in this situation?  One thought I had (after making this post originally) was to use a Wilcoxon Rank Sum on the differences.  Being rank based, it is distribution free but certainly less efficient.

Comment: PLease give context and details of the real-world situation. Maybe a logistic regression? ...

Comment: Survival modeling - predicting risk probabilities.

Comment: Actually, comparing changes in predicted risk probabilities over time.

Comment: What about Wilcoxon Rank Sums?  Being rank-based, it is distribution free and should not have a requirement of independence of variance and mean as the t-test does.

Comment: Please edit your question to include more details (not just a few words, as with your comments)

Comment: Post edited.  I don't know how much more detail I can provide, but I added some.  The question comes down to an alternative for the t-test due to non-independence of mean and variance in my data.

Comment: What you describe is **not** stochastic dependence, it is heteroskedasticity